# Having Issue on Using Prepared Statement For Ajax Login System

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am having trouble on getting result of login by using following Ajax and MySQLi Prepared Statement

```
var login = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "assets/app/users.php",
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log(data);
    },
    success: function() {}
});

login.done(function(html) {
    if(html=='true'){
        window.location.replace('app.php');
    }
    else  {
        $("#loginRequest").before('<div class="alert alert-danger err" role="alert">Email or Password Is Not Correct</div>');
    }
});
```

and this is the PHP on server side I hvae

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass  = $_POST['pass'];
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);                
$sql = "SELECT id, email, fname, lname, type FROM users WHERE `email`=? AND `pass`=?";              
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email,$pass);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($theId,$theEmail,$theFName,$theLname,$theType);
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo 'true';
    $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS'] = true;
    $_SESSION['fname'] = $theFName;
}
else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

I am sending the data correctly to server as I already test it on `beforeSend(){}` and `$_POST['email'];` which both return interred values. I also test the database with plain same SQL query which was functioning correctly but I am getting `false` in console in both valid and invalid credentials!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call `$stmt->store_result()` before you can use `$stmt->num_rows`.

Alternatively, you could just call `$stmt->fetch()` and test its result. It returns `true` when there's a row available, `null` when it reaches the end of the results.

```
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo 'true';
    $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS'] = true;
    $_SESSION['fname'] = $theFName;
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```